# What does this Fortran code do?

Tags: fortran

I was given some Fortran code (90, I believe) and I'm trying to figure out what it does. I know no Fortran, but do know Perl.

Here is a snippet that I've not been able to figure out:

```
  fmly='I:\CEX\Fmly'
  fmlyfile=fmly(1:23)//yearqtr(qtrcnt)
  open(unit=13,file=fmlyfile)
```

I know that `//` is a concatenation operator, but I'm confused about what the `fmly(1:23)` part is doing.

Answer (score 4):

`fmly(1:23)` is slicing a character string `fmly` from position `1` to position `23`. Note that in Fortran, string indexing begins from `1` and not from `0`. `fmly(1:23)` is equivalent to `fmly(:23)`.

Comment: Array indexing begins from `1` unless the array is declared with other bounds, e.g. `type, dimension(-10:10) :: array`.

Answer (score 3):

`string(A:B)` is a substring, selecting characters A to B of string `string`.   `fmly` is initialized with fewer than 23 characters, so the trailing characters will be blanks.  After that it will be concatenated with an element of the string array `yearqtr` (or possibly a string-valued function yearqtr).

Comment: `yearqtr(qtrcnt)` might also be a call to an external function that returns a string.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev is correct with an alternative possibility for yearqtr(qtrcnt).  A substring is ruled out by the syntax.  The variable names suggest "year quarter (quarter count)", which would be easy enough to do with a four-element array.